# Recursive function gives segmentation fault, how to point a pointer object to it's child?

Tags: c++, nodes, prefix-tree

So I have a prefixtree object that has multiple nodes. Each node consists of a character, whether it is a final node, and it's children stored in an object pointer array (up to 26 values). I need to print the words found beneath a given node.

Example below.

```
 a
/ \
b  c
    \
     t
```

If the function is called on the node with character 'a' it should print ab and act. I plan to do this by adding to a string until reach a node marked final and then removing that letter. I want to implement a recursive function but when setting a node to the child of that node I get a segmentation fault.

```
void PrefixTreeNode::printAllWords() const
{
  PrefixTreeNode* node; 

  for(char i = 'a'; i < 'a' + ALPHABET_SIZE; i++)
  {
    if(getChild(i) != nullptr)
    {
      if(!isFinal())
      {
        nodeList.push_back(i);
        cout << "added: " << i << endl;
        node = node->getChild(i);    //this line results to segmentation fault
        node->printAllWords();       //How would I call the function on the node's child?
      }
      else if(isFinal()) 
      {
        nodeList.push_back(i);
        cout << nodeList;
        nodeList.pop_back();
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Get child function:

```
PrefixTreeNode* PrefixTreeNode::getChild(char c)
{
  if (isalpha(c))
    return link[tolower(c)-'a'];
  else
    return nullptr;
}

const PrefixTreeNode* PrefixTreeNode::getChild(char c) const
{
  if (isalpha(c))
    return link[tolower(c)-'a'];
  else
    return nullptr;
}
```

Node Object:

```
class PrefixTreeNode
{
  friend PrefixTree;
private:
  char c;
  bool final;
  PrefixTreeNode* link[ALPHABET_SIZE];
public:
  //Constructs a new node
  PrefixTreeNode();
  //Copy constructor
  PrefixTreeNode(const PrefixTreeNode&);
  //Copy assignment
  const PrefixTreeNode& operator=(const PrefixTreeNode&);
  //Returns the character this node contains
  char getChar() const { return c; }
  //Returns whether this node is the end of a word
  bool isFinal() const { return final; }
  //Changes whether this node is the end of a word
  void setFinal(bool b) { final = b; }
  //Returns the node corresponding to the given character
  PrefixTreeNode* getChild(char);
  //Returns the node corresponding to the given character
  const PrefixTreeNode* getChild(char) const;
  //Adds a child corresponding to the given character
  void addChild(char);
  //Removes the child corresponding to the given character
  void deleteChild(char);
  //TODO:  print all words that end at or below this PrefixTreeNode
  void printAllWords() const;
  //Destructor
  ~PrefixTreeNode();
};
```

Comment: Can you share a [mcve]? I should be able to run your code and see the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Your node is not initialized when you call node->getChild(i). But your sample code is not complete, we don't know what getChild do.

Comment: `PrefixTreeNode* node;` is uninitialized. It points into the space between words, an amazing land of Undefined Behaviours. `node = node->getChild(i);` looks like it reaches into this mysterious wonderland looking for child nodes. This exploration rarely ends well.

Comment: @ggorlen since this involves objects with constructors, functions, and operator overloading what can I deem to be minimal?

Comment: @Nico238 please let me know if that added portion helps.

Comment: The " PrefixTreeNode* node; " auto var line appears wrong to me.  The function "void PrefixTreeNode::printAllWords() const" identifies the code as a function attribute of that node type.  Thus, consider removing " PrefixTreeNode* node; " and replacing all occurrances of " node-> " with " this-> ".  IMHO, your code should be operating on it's _own_ data attributes, not some uninitialized temporary.

Comment: @kingk the above link gives a very thorough explanation of minimal.

Comment: @2785528 Yes! I have instead made the recursive by writing this->getChild(i)->printAllWords(); Which rids of the error, thank you! Now I just need to solve my logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I just tell you why the line is caused of segment fault, I can say that you may initialize the variable node, above the line.

I couldn't know whole code, but I recommend to change it to like this.

```
void PrefixTreeNode::printAllWords() const
{
  for(char i = 'a'; i < 'a' + ALPHABET_SIZE; i++)
  {
    PrefixTreeNode* node = getChild(i); 
    //if(getChild(i) != nullptr)
    if(node != nullptr)
    {
      nodeList.push_back(i);//this line will be run, ALWAYS whatever the return of isFinal, so I moved it to here.
      if(!isFinal())
      {
        //nodeList.push_back(i); //moved to the front of 'if'
        cout << "added: " << i << endl;
        //just remove it
        //node = node->getChild(i);    //this line results to segmentation fault
        node->printAllWords();       //How would I call the function on the node's child?
      }
      //else if(isFinal()) //duplicated
      else
      {
        //nodeList.push_back(i); //moved to the front of 'if'
        cout << nodeList; //I don't know the type of nodeList, but you may take care of it.
        nodeList.pop_back();
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah.. the comments to explain the errors are already posted... while I'm writing this answer. Hm :(

Comment: I appreciate it man, means a lot that you took the time to write this out. Is it cool if I ask for your help to solve the logic behind it? nodeList is a string and I'm just trying to list all words out. so abc, abcd, and abcdef, are all words added but I am having issues removing deleting the right characters. Maybe you can help?

Comment: I solved it already lmao I really appreciate you taking your time to help out bro